# How to start the first plain javascript based web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have to create a platform independent mobile app. People have been suggesting to use Jquery-Mobile with PhoneGap. I just wanted to know that is there a standard skeleton(project structure) to start a js web app? Is there a command which will generate a basic skeleton of the project? This could be a generalized question, but please follow me to a tutorial or getting started with a project link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official structure that you have to follow. [Here](http://css.dzone.com/articles/build-your-first-mobile-app) is an introduction that walks through an example using `PhoneGap` and `jQuery Mobile`. I would recommend going through that to get familiar with the technology and then learning each one more in depth using online videos such as Pluralsight or Lynda or ordering one or two books off of amazon.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you intend the app to do, dictates which frameworks you use.

JQuery Mobile is a good choice if you want to do front end stuff, but there are alternatives such as 'The-M-Project' and others.

If the app is going to require a bit of back end stuff, maybe MeteorJS is a good place to look? It seems to behave fine with JQM (with the exception of panels).

It often comes down to personal preference and what it will be used for.

Apache Cordova is also a good alternative to PhoneGap (I believe it is the base of PhoneGap).

Hope it helps!
Joe